# IDE Plugin to handle Qooxdoo syntax

Tags: ide, qooxdoo

does anyone know about an IDE or eventually a (preferrably Aptana) IDE plug-in which adds support for Qooxdoo framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spket IDE has autocompletion support for qooxdoo:

http://spket.com/qooxdoo.html

Edit: Spket actually works fine with newer qooxdoo versions, just create a profile using a qooxdoo 1.3 SDK folder as shown in the linked page.

Comment: Pretty good, even if it supports only Qooxdoo 0.8 syntax, while qd is currently at 1.3. Btw very nice.